# Huge Azure Resource Cleanup - Need recommendations

Tags: azure, resources, resource-cleanup

So here’s the scoop... I have a large list of over 3000+ resources across multiple subscriptions and dev/production tenants that I need to clean up. These are all sorts of resources including storage, storage accounts, LogAnalytics, Azure App Service plans/ App Services, VMs, and many more. Phase 1 is to just simply turn off / break the services slightly to see if we can get the resource owners to claim the resources, so we don’t immediately want to go to deleting anything just yet. Then after a predetermined amount of time that we give them to claim the resources, any unclaimed will be deleted. I’ve got until the end of the month to get these 3000+ services temporarily interrupted, does anyone have any ideas on what’s i can do to interrupt them, a quick way to get the ones that are claimed back up and running, and then a deletion process for the unclaimed resources? Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 1):

it really depends, for some resources you can rotate access keys, some resources you can turn off. the problem with rotating keys, you cant rotate them back :) so owners would have to update their apps with new connection strings.

You can be less disruptive with certain PaaS offering, you can scale them down to the bare minimum, which means if they are being used for anything but dev they will likely suffer performance issues. That can be easily rolled back once you found the owner.

I'd suggest tag resources with some sort of `owner` tag once you know the owner and enforce that this tag must exist on all new resources with Azure Policy.

As for deleting, thats quite easy. Bunch of ways to delete stuff, again you can tag resources with certain tag to indicate you want to delete them and then search for all resources with that tag and delete them

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Do you have any suggestions on how I can target these different resources with some sort of scripting to semi-automate the process?

Comment: Get-AzResource -ODataQuery "`$filter=tagname eq 'something'" -ExpandProperties | Delete-AzResource -Force